# On click get data attribute and place inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a number of links with various data attributes assigned to them, and am trying to grab the content of `data-short-description` attribute when the link is clicked. The content of `data-short-description` would then be set into the `.description` div. This process would be repeated each time a different link is clicked, replacing the content inside `.description`.

I am able to hack JS but not fluent enough to write from scratch, so if somebody could help me using a mixture of (I assume) `.data()`,`.onclick()` etc that would be great.

A simplified version of my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="thumbnails">
    <figure class="thumbnail">
      <a href="#" data-short-description="DESCRIPTION 1 HERE!">
        <img src="#">
      </a>
    </figure>
    <figure class="thumbnail">
      <a href="#" data-short-description="DESCRIPTION 2 HERE!">
        <img src="#">
      </a>
    </figure>
    <figure class="thumbnail">
      <a href="#" data-short-description="DESCRIPTION 3 HERE!">
        <img src="#">
      </a>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="description">
    data-short-description to go here upon clicking link.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A huge thank you to @hexaholic for the following answer. Brilliant!

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="thumbnails">
        <figure class="thumbnail">
            <a class="description-link" href="#" data-short-description="DESCRIPTION 1 HERE!">
                <img src="#">
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure class="thumbnail">
            <a class="description-link" href="#" data-short-description="DESCRIPTION 2 HERE!">
                <img src="#">
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure class="thumbnail">
            <a class="description-link" href="#" data-short-description="DESCRIPTION 3 HERE!">
                <img src="#">
            </a>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="description">
    data-short-description to go here upon clicking link.
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="thumbnails">
        <figure class="thumbnail">
            <a class="description-link" href="#" data-short-description="DESCRIPTION 1 HERE!">
                <img src="#">
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure class="thumbnail">
            <a class="description-link" href="#" data-short-description="DESCRIPTION 2 HERE!">
                <img src="#">
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure class="thumbnail">
            <a class="description-link" href="#" data-short-description="DESCRIPTION 3 HERE!">
                <img src="#">
            </a>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="description">
    data-short-description to go here upon clicking link.
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // updates a description box with the value of the given link
        function updateDescription(link) {

            // find the parent container
            var parentContainer = link.closest('.container');

            // the description box comes right after the container
            var targetDiv = parentContainer.next();

            //finally, update the content
            targetDiv.html(link.attr('data-short-description'));
        };

        // fill in default description for each container
        $('.container').each(function() {
            var firstLink = $(this).find('.description-link').first();
            updateDescription(firstLink);
        });

        // change description when a link is clicked
        $('.description-link').click(function() {
            // call the update function
            updateDescription($(this));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your question with jQuery, I guess it's fine for me to use it.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.thumbnail a').click(function() {
            $('.description').html($(this).attr('data-short-description'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

But, as [alou mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33760585/3751577), you could provide a class for the links and give the target `div` an own `id`. I used `class="description-link"` and `id="description"`, so the whole thing looks like this:

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="thumbnails">
        <figure class="thumbnail">
            <a class="description-link" id="default-description" href="#" data-short-description="DESCRIPTION 1 HERE!">
                <img src="#">
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure class="thumbnail">
            <a class="description-link" href="#" data-short-description="DESCRIPTION 2 HERE!">
                <img src="#">
            </a>
        </figure>
        <figure class="thumbnail">
            <a class="description-link" href="#" data-short-description="DESCRIPTION 3 HERE!">
                <img src="#">
            </a>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="description">
    data-short-description to go here upon clicking link.
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // fill in default description on page load
        $('.description').html($('#default-description').attr('data-short-description'));

        // change description when a link is clicked
        $('.description-link').click(function() {
            $('#description').html($(this).attr('data-short-description'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @hexaholic. This is great, it works perfectly. One adjustment however, if possible, can I have the data attribute from the first link in place upon page load, at the moment #description is blank until a click is made?

Comment: Also, another issue I have just found (which is a result of me omitting information from the original question - sorry!).

I have multiple instances of this entire code sample on the page, approximately 17. When the links are clicked, I want the data to go into the relevent #description for that section. At the moment any click puts the data inside the first instance of that #description.

Any ideas?

Comment: @dungey_140 Sure you can. I updated my answer, adding the id `default-description` to the link you want to see first.

Comment: @dungey_140 Okay, if there are multiple description divs, you can either give them seperate IDs (like `description-01`, `description-02` etc), or go back to using `description` as a class name (since IDs must be unique) and locate the correct target div with some more jQuery logic. Can you provide some code, where more than one target div is present?

Comment: Firstly, I'm not able to get that default-description to work as I cannot add a class to just that individual thumbnail (the content is created dynamically). Is it possible to target the first thumbnail in a similar way to :nth-child in css?

Secondly, I have reverted to using a class as suggested as I am unable to give them separate ID's (again, generated dynamically). I have added additional code to the original question to help with solving this problem.

Thanks so much for your help! Nearly there :)

Comment: Sorry, I havn't been able to add the code to the question. Essentially however, if you take the block of code in the question and duplicate it 17 times, that is the markup. Thanks!

Comment: @dungey_140 I'll have a look at it soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95375/discussion-between-hexaholic-and-dungey-140).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
$('.thumbnail a').on('click', function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault(); //dont do default anchor stuff
  var description = $(this).data('short-description'); //get the text
  $('.description').html(description);
});
```

However it would be better to use a generic class for the specific set of links, like descriptionlink or something and use this to trigger the event `$('.descriptionlink').on('click'...` and an id for the target (maybe the same as the class, #description )

Other than that should be fine.